# I am new at programming an I am receiving a few different error messages when trying to use an add button for a txtarea from a txtfield

Tags: java

I have the following error codes:

```
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my event Action listener:

```
    @Override                          
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==addBtn)
            {
                {
                    Student stu = createStudent();
                    students.add(stu);

                }

                showStudents();
            }
```

Here is my createStudent:

```
private Student createStudent(){

    String fN = fnameTxt.getText();
    String lN = lnameTxt.getText();
    String ma = majorTxt.getText();
    String gp = gpaTxt.getText();
    String ui = uinTxt.getText();
    String ne = netidTxt.getText();
    String ag = ageTxt.getText();
    String ge = genderTxt.getText();
    return new Student(fN,lN, ma, gp, ui, ne, ag, ge );
}
```

Comment: Show us the whole stack trace. The part you showed us isn't useful.

Comment: Please include more of the error text.  Especially the *topmost* part: the part that says the actual error.  Just guessing - it's possibly a "NullPointerException".  Which could be caused by failing to initialize a variable.  If so, you'll also need to copy the code where you think you're initializing that variable.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionExceptio
n: Conversion = '-'

Comment: Q: Can you show us where you're using `java.util.Scanner()`?

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following error codes:

Those are not "error codes".  They are *part of* a Java stacktrace.

If we can see the entire stacktrace, then it may be possible to figure out what it means. However, the lines you have included provided nothing that can (realistically) be used for diagnostic purposes.

---

You added this:

> java.util.UnknownFormatConversionExceptio n: Conversion = '-'

This is telling us that somewhere in your code you are directly or indirectly using a `Format` (or similar) to generate or parse a string.  It would appear that the format string is incorrect.

My guess is that this is happening in your `showStudents()` method, but without a complete stacktrace (and the code of that method) it is not possible to be sure.

Comment: Why is this an answer and not a comment?

Comment: Because it an answer and not a comment.  It is an answer based on the scant information that has been provided.

Comment: I used a format in my toString from the student class. I want it to show up as rows.

Comment: I might use a format.  Or I might do it another way.  Anyhow, it seems like the bug in your code is in the format string.  Read the javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) carefully and make sure that you have got it right.

Answer (score 0):

With Stephen C help,  I was able to find a format error in my Student class toString method. I wanted it as a row but it was not formatted correctly. It now reads and works find as follows:
    public String toString() {

```
return String.format("%-15s %-15s\n", "First Name", firstName) +
       String.format("%-15s %-15s\n", "Last Name", lastName) +
        String.format("%-15s %-15s\n", "Major", major) +
        String.format("%-15s %-15s\n", "GPA", gpa) +
        String.format("%-15s %-15s\n", "UIN", UIN) +
        String.format("%-15s %-15s\n", "Net ID", netID) +
        String.format("%-15s %-15s\n", "Age", age) +
        String.format("%-15s %-15s\n", "Gender", gender);


}
```